# Postgresql Stored Procedures: Using id from one statement in another

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a stored procedure with two insert statements where id/primary_key from the first insert statement will be used in second.

For eg.

`INSERT INTO activity VALUES (DEFAULT, 'text', 'this is a test');`

If the id returned from the above statement is **x**, the second insert will be like:

`INSERT INTO activity_tree VALUES (DEFAULT, **x**, user_id) or something like that.`

I understand thatlibpq has functions which can give the id from the first statement.

But I want to combine them into a stored procedure. Please advise.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a variable, e.g. `new_id` and then you can store the generate id in there:

```
INSERT INTO activity VALUES (DEFAULT, 'text', 'this is a test')
   RETURNING id INTO new_id;

INSERT INTO activity_tree VALUES (DEFAULT, new_id, user_id);
```

This assumes the column where the value is generated is called `id`

Btw: do not use "unqualified" insert statements. Always specify the columns in the INSERT part. That makes your code much more stable:

```
INSERT INTO activity (id, some_column, other_column) 
VALUES 
(DEFAULT, 'text', 'this is a test')
```

And make sure you are not calling variables the same way as columns. `user_id` seems to be a potential naming conflict here. This will compile with 8.x but might give you strange errors. I think this will no longer compile with 9.x

Comment: **Excellent** Info. Thanks a lot. I'll take care of each and everything you suggested. Thanks once again

Comment: Accepted. I did not know about this provision. I'm relatively new to Stackoverflow :)